# Picture changing in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, imageicon

So i'm making a GUI in java.
Say I have a Constructor method, say

```
        public class glmb extends JLabel implements ActionListener {
           public glmb(){
            Container C= getContentPane();
            C.setLayout(null);
                    myLabel.setBounds(0,0,30,30);
                    myLabel.setBounds(30,0,30,30);
            C.add(myLabel);
            C.add(myButt);
            MyButt.addActionListener(this);
                   setSize(400,400);
                   setVisible(true);
           }}
```

I have a JLabel with an ImageIcon inside the class:

```
           JLabel myLabel =new JLabel(new ImageIcon("mypic1.jpg"));
```

A button with an Action Listener, which will make the JLabel myLabel change the picture:

```
             if(e.getSource()==myButt)
             { myLabel =new JLabel(new ImageIcon("mypic2.jpg")); setSize(50,50);}
```

How do I make the picture change in the JFrame after I press the button, the button works because the frame changed size(see the setSize(50,50))? Thank You!!! Still new to java here, haha

Comment: You've changed the reference to myLabel, which no longer points to what's on the screen, so what ever you do to it, it will never change what's on the screen. Instead, simply use the reference to myLabel and use setIcon to change its image.

Comment: null layout is very rarely the answer to building dynamic and portable user interfaces as each system has its own font metrics and rendering differences. You should consider making use of an appropriate layout manager or compound layouts as required and let the API take care of these dirty details

Comment: MadProgrammer,i did not understand what you said(I'm 14 y/o in high school), yea but say the setSize works, the frame changed its size, so, how do I add the JLabel to the container(look above). I added the label in the container, which then sets visible the image. How Do I add the JLabel again in the same container?

Comment: You don't. You already have JLabel on the screen, you simply need to change the properties of the instance you already have

Comment: How?(I'm sorry, still new to programming here. Thanks for the patience BTW)

Comment: How do I put the pic2.jpg in setIcon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using

`myLabel =new JLabel(new ImageIcon("mypic2.jpg"));`

use

`myLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("mypic2.jpg"));`

if i understand correctly this should work for you.

Comment: Yep!!! Thank you very much!!!! Still new to programming here, so your help is very appreciated!